# How to render react components for a particular timestamp

Tags: reactjs, time, timestamp, comparison, state

I am new to React. I am building an employee time tracker application in which I want to render "lunch icon" for a particular time interval (eg. from 11:00:00 AM to 1:00:00 PM - 12hrs format). How do I use this.state.currentTime (in the below code) for this?

```
class Options extends React.Component {

  state = {
    currentTime: new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
   }

renderLunchIcon(employee){
  if(employee.isLoggedIn === true && *this.state.currentTime between '11:00:00 AM' and '1:00:00 PM'*){
    return (
    <div class="field">
    <Link onClick={this.handleLunch}>
      <h3><i class="black massive utensils icon"></i></h3>
      <label><h1 id="text-color">Lunch</h1></label>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
  }
}
}
```

kindly guide me through this.

Comment: it might be easier to keep the date as a date object in the state and then you can use `date.gethours()` to get the current hour in 24 hour format, and then test if its between 11 and 13

Comment: @WebbH - Thankyou.. This works!!!